# Set of non-decreasing function in bijection with R

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I've learnt and understood the demonstration for "the set of all non-decreasing function is uncountable" with the diagonalization proof, but how could i demonstrate it is in bijection with R (the set of real numbers) or that the two sets are equipotent.

Comment: showing that set is uncountable is trivial: define $f_c:\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ by $f_c \equiv c$ for $c\in \mathbf{R}$, so it has an uncountable subset.  No diagonalization needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start: Such a function can be completely specified by a countable family of real numbers: The value of the function at each rational number, plus the location of all discontinuities, plus the value of the function at each point of discontinuity.

Answer (score 2):

To identify a function it is enough to know its value on rational numbers and on the discontinuities. In fact the value on a continuity point $x$ is determined as the limit on rational points approaching $x$. A non-decreasing function has only a countable number of discontinuities, hence it is enough to know its value on a countable number of points.